# Set timezone globally in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-moment, angular-date-format

I'm building my first project in Angular 6 using Redux. In my last projects I used AngularJS, where I imported **moment Library** and, after the user logged in, I set the default timezone:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
```

I need the same behaviour in my Angular application: all the date that I'm going to display will be in UTC format. How can I achieve this in Angular 6? Is moment Library still a good practice? Because I would'nt like to set (maybe with a Pipe) the format every time I use a date, but configure it globally.

Thank you for the support!

Comment: I don't see any potential problems that Angular might have with your Approach that AngularJS wouldn't also have had. Why wouldn't you just try it?

Comment: Because maybe there are others best practice :)

Comment: This problem seems specific enough that there probably aren't ;)

Comment: I'm going to try thanks :D